# Synchronization of Intellij/PyCharm with installed python modules

Tags: python, mysql-python

I do not understand how Intellij "finds" the installed python modules.

Here is an example:  I have installed the python mysqldev

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

It is working on command line python. But IJ does not see it

```
  File "/shared/git2/etl/appminer/hive/DB.py", line 7, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

So how to make IJ aware of the installed python libs?

thanks